# Python- Key from dict on user input eval. Send to overloaded operator function

Tags: python, function, variables, operators, eval

For starters here is my current code:

```
import ipaddress

class Net():
    def __init__(self, ip, mask):
        self.ip = ip
        self.mask = mask

    def getipmask(self):
        return self.ip, self.mask

    def __mul__(self, ip1, ip2, sn1):

        ip1_Bin = [bin(int(ip1))[2:].rjust(8,'0') for ip1 in ip1.split('.')]
        IP1 = ''.join(ip1_Bin)
        ip2_Bin = [bin(int(ip2))[2:].rjust(8,'0') for ip2 in ip2.split('.')]
        IP2 = ''.join(ip2_Bin)
        sn_Bin = [bin(int(sn1))[2:].rjust(8,'0') for sn1 in sn1.split('.')]
        SUB1 = ''.join(sn_Bin)
        IP1Final = (IP1 + "/" + SUB1)
        IP2Final = (IP2 + "/" + SUB1)
        if ipaddress.ip_address(IP1Final) in ipaddress.ip_network(IP2Final, strict=False):
            print("")
            print("Same Subnet!")
        else:
            print("")
            print("Different Subnet!")

userIP = None

name_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
net_dict = {}

while True:
    userIP = input("Enter IP (type 'end' to exit): ")
    if userIP == 'end':
        break
    userMask = input("Enter Mask: ")
    name = name_list.pop(0)
    net_dict[name] = Net(userIP, userMask)

#print out all ip/mask combos with proper names
print('')
for x in net_dict:
    print(x, "-->", net_dict[x].getipmask())
print('')

#evaluations
while True:
    userFuncIn = input("Please enter a function (e.g. A+B). Enter 'end ' to stop: ")
    charList = list(userFuncIn)
    #Get the object letters
    charList_Objs = charList[0:][::2]
    #Get the operators
    charList_Ops = charList[1:][::2]
    #assign letter value to proper ip and subnet values
    for x in charList_Objs:
         x = net_dict[x].getipmask()
    #Get number of operators
    numberofOps = len(charList_Ops)
    #while charList_Ops still has operations
    while len(charList_Ops) != 0:
       #current operator
       operator = charList_Ops.pop(0)
       #xpression with proporly assigned values on objects
       expression = [charList_Objs[0], operator, charList_Objs[1]]
       #convert from list to string to use in eval
       exp_str = "".join(expression)
       #Delete objects 0 and 1 from the charList
       del(charList_Objs[0:1])
       print(eval(exp_str))
```

What should be happening is after all the user's inputs are displayed with their corresponding letter they are able to enter what function they want to preform. For now to keep it simple I am just focusing on `__mul__`. What `__mul__` will do is take in two IP/subnet combos and evaluate them to see if they are on the same subnet. I can fix the code in the `__mul__` function once I properly figure out how I am to get the user's function entry to work properly. So if user enters `A*B`. It should take `A` and `B` from `net_dict` and then send those 2 key/value pairs to the overridden `__mul__` function to perform. The correct action.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

PS: Other functions (not `__mul__`) will allow for multiple operations and multiple IP/subnet pairs. For example (`A+B+C`) so that is why I added `charList_Ops` and `charlist_Objs`. If it was just a case where there was always 3 chars in the user entered function (e.g. `A*B`) that would obviously not be needed.

Comment: "Part 2 from my question from before" is meaningless.  Make your questions self-contained.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Ned! I'll keep that in mind my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky. The naive way to do this is of course just `eval`, but that's ugly. Instead let's do this:

```
import re
import operator

operators = {"*": operator.mul,
             "+": operator.add,
             "-": operator.sub,
             "/": operator.truediv} # add or delete from this dict as desired

re_splitters = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(splitter) for splitter in operators.keys()])

user_input = input("Here's a prompt! ")
Alice, Bob = map(net_dict.get, re_splitters.split(user_input))
# this may give you errors if you have a poorly formed user input. Catch and handle
# those errors as appropriate

action = re_splitters.search(user_input).group(0)

result = operators[action](Alice, Bob)
```

You could also do:

```
Alice, Bob = re_splitters.split(user_input)
# YOU MUST CHECK HERE THAT ALICE AND BOB ARE BOTH IN net_dict
action = re_splitters.search(user_input).group(0)
if action:
    result = eval("net_dict[{}] {} net_dict[{}]".format(Alice, action, Bob))
    # strong warning about an injection vulnerability!
```

But imagine the case where you fail to check if `Alice` and `Bob` are in `net_dict` and a malicious user does:

```
>> # User input below:
known_key];import os;os.system("format C:");net_dict[known_key+known_key
```

Which then becomes:

```
net_dict[known_key]
import os
os.system("format C:")
net_dict[known_key] + net_dict[known_key]
```

Congratulations, the hard drive is now toast.

Comment: Note that this will NOT handle `A*B*C` as your afterword mentions may be possible with other operators. You'll need to make your parser a little more complex for that, which goes slightly beyond the scope of this question (i.e. do you follow the normal order of operations?? etc)

Comment: A simple way of handling multiple operators while staying with this framework might be `objects = map(net_dict.get, re.splitters.split(...` (instead of `Alice, Bob = map(...` and `operators = re_splitters.findall(user_input)` (instead of `action = re_splitters.search(...`) but it still begs the question of how you APPLY those operators to each other.

Comment: First off, thank you very much. I get the following error when trying to implement your code. "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/iMac/PycharmProjects/Assignment7/Q1.py", line 67, in <module>
    A, B = re_splitters.split(user_input)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: @user3002598 what's your input string?

Comment: A*B (changed alice and bob to a and b respectively)

Comment: @user3002598 whoops that's because I had a fundamental mistake in how `re.split` works. I'll edit, but instead of doing `re_splitters = re.compile(''.join(...` you'll want to do `re_splitters = re.compile('|'.join(...` (in other words, you'll be splitting by `+` OR `*` OR `-` OR ``\``, not a literal ``*+-/`` like I'd mistakenly written)

Comment: Ok great. Got that sorted. Now I'm getting that a str object has no attribute get(). "    result = A.get(funcs[action])(B)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: @user3002598 sounds like something is more fundamentally wrong. You should be storing `Net` objects in your `net_dict` dictionary. Though I also made a typo there, it should be `Alice.__dict__.get(funcs[action])(B)`. However that's not the cause of this error. What kind of objects are in your `net_dict`?

Comment: print(type(net_dict[name])) prints out <class '__main__.Net'> So Net objects are being stored.

Comment: @user3002598 then I'd double check your code as transcribed. If you're doing `Alice, Bob = map(net_dict.get, ...` then you should be getting `Net` objects for `Alice` and `Bob`, not strings as your error indicates. (Also, enclosing words in backticks (`\``) will make them appear as in-line code blocks)

Comment: Ok we are getting somewhere. (Really wish I could have used chat for this). Now I get NoneType object is not callable on line  result = A.__dict__.get(funcs[action])(B). Assume this means A or B has no value? They appear to reference their correct values when I went to print them though.

Comment: @user3002598 might mean your `__mul__` function is broken. Does it behave well in unit testing?

Comment: It seems to. I pass it in A and B.
Problem is I don't even think it gets into the function. I tried by adding a print statement right at the top of the function and it doesn't get to it.

Comment: @user3002598 hmm you're right. The problem's in my code. You can't access `some_object.__mul__` the way I'm trying to. That said, you should definitely look at your `Net.__mul__` definition because it IS wrong, it's just not wrong the way I thought it was :D `A * B` fails.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So where should I go from here? Any other ideas?

Comment: After implementing your changes. I get "    result = operators[action](A, B)
TypeError: __mul__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'"..... Not sure what is wrong with my function.

Comment: GOT IT! Had to remove self as a variable in the function. THANK YOU SO MUCH.